# RTSP proxying with Caddy

Tags: reverse-proxy, rtsp, caddy, caddyfile

#### Problem

I'm using [MediaMTX](https://github.com/aler9/mediamtx) to [proxy](https://github.com/aler9/mediamtx/#proxy-mode) an RTSP stream via a WebRTC endpoint. The MediaMTX server exposes a WebRTC endpoint on port `8889`.

I need to run the MediaMTX server on a VPS which is using Caddy as a reverse proxy and a static server to serve some other files. I want to reverse proxy a certain path to port `8889` but I get `application/x-unknown-filetype` errors in the frontend.

#### Current setup

- `Caddyfile`

  ```
    my-server.com {
        handle_path /relay/* {
            @denied not remote_ip forwarded private_ranges
            abort @denied

            reverse_proxy :8889
        }
    }
  ```
- Usage in frontend

  ```html
  <iframe src="https://my-server.com/relay/$cameraID"></iframe>
  ```

#### Potential causes/solutions

- After a little digging, I found out that this might be happening because Caddy doesn't support raw TCP traffic. [`caddy-l4`](https://github.com/mholt/caddy-l4) might be of help.
- Right now, I'm using MediaMTX to convert RTSP ➡ WebRTC and expose it to the frontend. I might try with other methods like HLS.